# Why java date is not parsable?

Tags: java, hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

I am developing a mobile application using oracle MAF. Oracle MAF provides its date component and if I select a date then output is like : `2015-06-16T04:35:00.000Z` for selected date `Jun 16, 2015 10:05 AM`.

I am trying to convert this format to "Indian Standard Time" with .ical (ICalendar Date format) which should be like `20150613T100500` for the selected date `Jun 16, 2015 10:05 AM`. I am using code below:

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
String start_date_time = isoFormat.parse("20150616T043500000Z").toString();
```

But it returns date time as :

```
Tue Jun 16 04:35:00 GMT+5:30 2015
```

And should be like:

```
20150616T100500
```

Comment: How does the pattern `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss` match the value of `2015-06-16T04:35:00.000Z`? Maybe something like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSZ` might work

Comment: For the format of `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss`, you need to be using `20150613T100500` as the value to parse.

Comment: Thanks that resolved exception, I used 20150616T043500000Z as string but it returns "Tue Jun 16 04:35:00 GMT+5:30 2015", what is the way to convert to tile like 20150613T100500 , and why it is showing time as 04:35 while I am passing time as 10:05.

Comment: The original value is in UTC, so when you parse it, you need to make sure you're using UTC as the time zone.  When you format it, you want to use IST

Comment: `String start_date_time = isoFormat.parse("20150616T043500000Z").toString();` is wrong, this is relying on the internal format of `Date` to provide `String` representation of the object, it carries no internal concept of formatting.  Instead, use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the parsed `Date` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the value from `2015-06-16T04:35:00.000Z` UTC to a `java.util.Date`

```
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
from.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date start_date_time = from.parse("2015-06-16T04:35:00.000Z");
```

Which gives us a `java.util.Date` of `Tue Jun 16 14:35:00 EST 2015` (for me).

Then, you need to format this in IST

```
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
outFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
String formatted = outFormat.format(start_date_time);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Which outputs `20150616T100500`

## Java 8 Time API

Just because it's good practice...

```
    // No Time Zone
    String from = "2015-06-16T04:35:00.000Z";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(from, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
    
    // Convert it to UTC
    ZonedDateTime zdtUTC = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    // Convert it to IST
    ZonedDateTime zdtITC = zdtUTC.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Indian/Cocos"));
    String timestamp = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss").format(zdtITC);
    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

nb: If I didn't parse the value to `LocalDateTime`, then convert it to `UTC`, I was out by an hour, but I'm open to knowing better ways

Answer (score 0):

Supply format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    try {
        Date start_date_time = isoFormat.parse("2015-06-16T04:35:00.000Z");
        System.out.println(start_date_time);
        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
        String formattedTime = output.format(start_date_time);
        System.out.println(formattedTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Tue Jun 16 04:35:00 IST 2015
20150616T043500
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be coming out as `20150616T100500`?

Comment: `10:05` not `04:35`, but yes, the date values in the original post are mixed up :P

Answer (score 0):

A few additions to the format, and a correct TZ in the date string:

```
 SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
 isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
 String start_date_time = isoFormat.parse("2015-06-16T04:35:00.000CEST").toString();
```